# what's wrong with this if/then stored proc?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm fuzzy on when I need you use @ to reference vars in mySQL.  I'm coming from MS SQL where you always use it, but apparently that's not correct in mySQL.

So the below stored procedure is always executing the first IF block, even if the session value is expired - in that it's always executing the update statement.  Apparently the only debug tool I could find for mySQL stored procs runs on Windows and Linux.  I'm on a Mac.  Wamp wamp wamp.

So yeah.  Can anyone see what's wrong here?  Thanks!

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`xxx`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `validate_session`(uid INT, token VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN
    DECLARE sessId INT DEFAULT NULL;

    SELECT sessId = id FROM UserSessions
    WHERE userId = uid
    AND sessionToken = token
    AND expires > INTERVAL 2 MINUTE + NOW() ORDER BY expires DESC LIMIT 1;

IF sessId IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE UserSessions 
    SET expires = INTERVAL 2 HOUR + NOW() 
    WHERE id = sessId;
ELSE
    DELETE FROM UserSessions 
    WHERE userId = uid 
    AND sessionToken = token;
    SET @sessId = 0;

END IF;

SELECT sessId;
END
```

For the record what it's supposed to do in pseudo code:

```
if we have a session for this user, with a matching token which has not expired {
    update the expiration time to 2 hours from now
    return the session id;
}
else {
    delete the (now stale) session
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Barranka covered the main issue I see in his answer below; but I am not sure why the first IF block would EVER execute in your version as sessId should always be NULL. Also, if you actually want a return value instead of a resultset, a stored FUNCTION might better fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the value of `sessId`... you're making a comparisson in your query.

I think what you need is something like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxx`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `validate_session`(uid INT, token VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN
    DECLARE sessId INT DEFAULT NULL;

    SELECT id 
        INTO sessId -- Here is the assignment
    FROM UserSessions
    WHERE userId = uid
      AND sessionToken = token
      AND expires > INTERVAL 2 MINUTE + NOW() 
    ORDER BY expires DESC 
    LIMIT 1;

    IF sessId IS NOT NULL THEN
        UPDATE UserSessions 
            SET expires = INTERVAL 2 HOUR + NOW() 
            WHERE id = sessId;
    ELSE
        DELETE FROM UserSessions 
            WHERE userId = uid 
            AND sessionToken = token;
        SET sessId = 0;
   END IF;

   SELECT sessId;
END
```

Reference:

- [MySQL Reference: `SELECT ... INTO` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html)
- [MySQL Reference: Local variable scope and resolution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/local-variable-scope.html)